# No consigo validar email usando regex

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de hacer un ejercicio sencillo de validación de email pero no consigo que funcione. A la hora de testealo siempre me devuelve que la dirección es incorrecta. Dónde está mi error?

```
<body>
<form action="" name="emailValidator">
    <p>ESCRIBE TU EMAIL</p><br />
    E-mail <input type="email" id="email"><br />
    <button type="button" name="boton1" onclick='validarEmail(email)'>Comprobar</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validarEmail(email) {

        var regex = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3,4})+$/;
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;

        if (regex.test(email)) {
            alert("La dirección de email " + email + " es correcta.");
        } else {
            alert("La dirección de email es incorrecta.");
        }


    }
</script>
```

Gracias

Comment: puedes poner los casos de prueba que has probado?

Comment: Si. hola@gmail.com /hola@hotmail.com/hola@icloud.com/hola@yahoo.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu variable regex debería contener el valor `/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/`.

Para entender esta expresión regular la dividiré en **componentes más pequeños**:

`/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+:`  Significa que la dirección de email debe empezar con caracteres alfanuméricos (tanto minúsculas como mayúsculas están permitidas). **Puede tener puntos, guiones bajos y guiones.**

`@:`   Debe haber un símbolo '@' después de los caracteres iniciales.

`[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+:` Después del signo '@', debe haber algunos caracteres alfanuméricos. Puede contener también puntos (.) y guiones (-).

`\.:` Después del segundo grupo de caracteres, debe haber un punto. Esto es para separar el nombre de dominio de los subdominios.

`[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/:` Finalmente, la dirección de correo electrónico debe terminar de dos a cuatro letras. Teniendo a-z y A-Z significa que se permiten letras minúsculas y mayúsculas.
`{2,4}` indica el número mínimo y máximo de caracteres. Esto permitirá nombres de dominio con 2, 3 y 4 caracteres, por ejemplo; us, es, tx, org, com, net, wxyz).

Por tanto, poniendo los valores de `regex` tal que **así**, funciona correctamente:

```html
<body>
<form action="" name="emailValidator">
    <p>ESCRIBE TU EMAIL</p><br />
    E-mail <input type="email" id="email"><br />
    <button type="button" name="boton1" onclick='validarEmail(email)'>Comprobar</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validarEmail(email) {

        var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;

        if (regex.test(email)) {
            alert("La dirección de email " + email + " es correcta.");
        } else {
            alert("La dirección de email es incorrecta.");
        }


    }
</script>
```

Comment: Cualquier duda que tengas, me comentas.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con esta expresión regular

```
/^\w+([\.\+\-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/
```

Esta expresión además permite usar el carácter **+**.

Comment: Gracias, funciona!

Comment: De nada!! @RománCano